# How to Pass a Value from a PowerShell file to Yaml

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml

I have 2 PowerShell Files and a Yaml file used as a pipeline. I have Filename1.ps1 which returns a value and would like to get that value passed to yaml file which would be used to run another powershell file named Filename2.The yaml file used is as below.

```
name: '1.0$(rev:.r)'

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

trigger: none

stages:
- stage: Check_Latest_Build
  jobs:
  - job: Check_Pull_Request_Validation_Status
    steps:
    # - task: 
    #   displayName: Check Pipeline Build
    - powershell: .\Filename1.ps1

    - powershell: .\Filename2.ps1 -BuildName $BuildId
```

I get the error that $BuildId is empty from FileName2.
I also tried changing it to.

```
.\Filename2.ps1 -BuildName $(BuildId)
```

Still No luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the output of the `FileName1.ps1` and set it to an [output variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell). This can be done as

```
$output = .\Filename1.ps1
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildId;isOutput=true]$output"
```

Then you need to [reference the output variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks) from your first task in your second step, which can be done as below (assuming `step1` is the name of the first powershell task

```
.\Filename2.ps1 -BuildName $(step1.BuildId)
```

**Putting it all together:**

```yaml
name: '1.0$(rev:.r)'

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

trigger: none

stages:
- stage: Check_Latest_Build
  jobs:
  - job: Check_Pull_Request_Validation_Status
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        name: step1
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |
            $output = .\Filename1.ps1
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildId;isOutput=true]$output"

      - powershell: .\Filename2.ps1 -BuildName $(step1.BuildId)
```